# ESLint doesn't run for HTML files in PyCharm

Tags: javascript, html, pycharm, eslint

I am working on a Django+JavaScript project using ESLint as an integrated linter in PyCharm. It works well for `*.js` files but doesn't analyze any JavaScript in `*.html` files at all. How do I enable ESLint for HTML files, too?

**Here is what I have tried**

I added the `eslint-plugin-html` and followed its setup instructions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-html

This includes adding `"plugins": [ "html" ]` into `.eslintrc.js` and adding `--ext .html,.js` into the "Extra ESLint options" input box in "Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint" at PyCharm Preferences.

Here is what my `.eslintrc.js` file looks like (rules are skipped). I commented out the ESLint vue plugin so far as it is said to have incompatibilities with eslint-plugin-html, which didn't help either.

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        //"plugin:vue/essential",
        "google"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "plugins": [
        "html",
        //"vue"
    ],
    "rules": {
        ...
    }
};
```

Here is the screenshot of my ESLint settings in PyCharm preferences:
[ESLint settings in PyCharm preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRYiC.png)

Comment: Would you like to lint JavaScript code in Django templates, or in static HTML files? the latter works fine using your config, but linting Python templates is not currently supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important matter is that HTML files in my case were used as Django templates (which is the standard approach for the scenario I'm describing i.e. for Django projects). As explained by **lena** in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317478/eslint-doesnt-run-for-html-files-in-pycharm#comment101401087_57317478) above, linting Django templates is not currently supported. I've got the same confirmation from an official request to JetBrains (the company that owns PyCharm).

So the answer is - **currently there is no way to enable ESLint for Django templates in PyCharm**. The workaround is to move the JS code to the other supported types of files to have the code linted (for example, .js or .vue files).

JetBrains has opened a new issue in their tracking system for adding the lacking support, so please vote there if this feature matters to you: [ESLint: support linting JavaScript code in Django templates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40863). Also, **use this link to get most recent updates on whether this feature gets supported**.